# Die a Noun: died a hero

Tags: idioms

I know the following form is possible.

> *"He died a hero."* = *"He died the death of a hero."*

In light of this, can I also say something like these?

> *"He died a poor man."
>
> "He died a happy man."
>
> "He died a good teacher."*
> etc.....

Comment: “He **died** the **death** of...” looks very awkward to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say "He died *a noun*" means "He died **while being** *a noun*". So it makes sense "He died while being a poor man" or "He died while being a happy man".

You could also say "He died while being a good teacher", but I don't think I would understand what that means. Does that mean he was in the act of teaching when he died?

Now, imagine that there is a school on fire and a teacher dies while trying to save a student from the fire. You could say "he died a hero" and "he died a good teacher" and I would understand both.

Comment: "_To say "He died a noun" means "He died while being a noun"._" Right, but there is also "He died a lonely death" which also accords with the same pattern "He died a noun".

Comment: @Gabe - If he used his last breaths to e.g. explain an algebra problem to someone, you could say he died a teacher.

Comment: Hi, I mean, what I am trying to say something by "die a hero / die a teacher" is that somebody died as a hero while he did something like a hero always does. Likewise, somebody died as a teacher and he had taught something in his/her life.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer by Gabe indicates, "He died a hero" usually means "he was heroic at the moment of his death" or "he died in the course of a heroic action." However, the more general form 'He died an X" often means simply "He was an X when he died." For example "He died a poor man" does not imply that he was losing money at the moment of his death, merely that he had little then.  invented context:

> He made a fortune, but it lost it to a corrupt manager. He died a poor man.

Other possible example:

> He was born a Catholic, but converted at the time of his marriage. He died a Jew.

> He continued to instruct others informally lo9ng after his retirement. He died a teacher.

The phrases  "died a hero" and "died a poor man" are fairly common. Something like "died a teacher" is unusual.